# NuGet - add a new package feed from command line

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, nuget, command-line-interface, nuget-package

I have a scenario where im creating a build in VSTS. I don't have access to the VM hosting the Agent and it's not setup to include our internal package feed.

I do have access via the command line (powershell) - how do I add a new package feed to VS2017 via the command line? (or can I even do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "MyServer" -Source \\myserver\packages
```

See detailed reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-sources).
Or add the feed to file `NuGet.config` manually. You can find `NuGet.config` using the following path:

```
$env:APPDATA\NuGet\Nuget.config
```